# How to truncate .000 zeros from double with NSNumberFormatter

Tags: objective-c, xcode, decimal, string-formatting, nsnumberformatter

Ok so if I have a double to begin with how do I limit it or truncate digits to 1dp since I know they're not needed to be viewed

```
double a = 1.6;

NSNumberFormatter *numberFormatter = [[NSNumberFormatter alloc] init];
NSString *numberAsString = [numberFormatter stringFromNumber:[NSNumber numberWithDouble:a]];

[numberFormatter setNumberStyle:NSNumberFormatterDecimalStyle];
[numberFormatter setGeneratesDecimalNumbers:YES];
[numberFormatter setMaximumFractionDigits:1];
[numberFormatter setMinimumFractionDigits:1];
[numberFormatter setAlwaysShowsDecimalSeparator:YES];  

NSLog(@"a raw: %f", a); //outputs 1.600000

myLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",numberAsString];

NSLog(@"Formatted a: %@", numberAsString); //outputs 2

[numberFormatter release];
```

So the problem is it rounds the value and leaves no decimal place, I'm trying to get it to output just 1.6 for myLabel.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7469614/remove-more-than-2-trailing-zero/7470191#7470191

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure but you can try with `NSString *formatted = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%.1f", a];`, then use the formatted as the label text