# Remove More Than 2 Trailing zero

Tags: iphone, objective-c, string-formatting, precision

I have read many question in stack overflow, what I want is remove 2 or more than two trailing zero behind the decimal. i.e:

```
12.00 ==> 12
12.30 ==> 12.30
12.35 ==> 12.35
12.345678 ==> 12.34
```

Comment: which language/technology are u using?

Comment: `iPhone` tag, so I assume Obj-C/Cocoa

Comment: may be this could help you ..


http://stackoverflow.com/questions/829067/how-can-i-round-a-float-value-to-2-post-decimal-positions

Comment: it is different. I want to retain one zero behind decimal, but remove zero that more than 2

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
NSNumberFormatter *twoDecimalPlacesFormatter = [[[NSNumberFormatter alloc] init] autorelease];
[twoDecimalPlacesFormatter setMaximumFractionDigits:2];
[twoDecimalPlacesFormatter setMinimumFractionDigits:0];

return [twoDecimalPlacesFormatter stringFromNumber:number];
```

Answer (score 3):

I like @dorada's answer, here is a complete test:

```
NSNumberFormatter *formatter = [[NSNumberFormatter alloc] init];
[formatter setMaximumFractionDigits:2];
[formatter setMinimumFractionDigits:0];

NSLog(@"12.00 ==> %@", [formatter stringFromNumber:[NSNumber numberWithFloat:12.00]]);
NSLog(@"12.30 ==> %@", [formatter stringFromNumber:[NSNumber numberWithFloat:12.30]]);
NSLog(@"12.35 ==> %@", [formatter stringFromNumber:[NSNumber numberWithFloat:12.35]]);
NSLog(@"12.345678 ==> %@", [formatter stringFromNumber:[NSNumber numberWithFloat:12.345678]]);
```

NSLog output:

```
12.00 ==> 12
12.30 ==> 12.3
12.35 ==> 12.35
12.345678 ==> 12.35
```

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
NSLog(@"%0.2f", 12.345678);
```

Or to save it to an NSString:

```
NSString *numberString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%0.2f", 12.345678];
```

**Edit**

Missed the fact that you didn't want any zero fraction digits. Credits to @dorada for this one:

```
NSNumber *number = [NSNumber numberWithFloat:12.00];
NSNumberFormatter *formatter = [[NSNumberFormatter alloc] init];
[formatter setMaximumFractionDigits:2];
[formatter setMinimumFractionDigits:0];

NSString *numberString = [formatter stringFromNumber:number];
[formatter release];
```

Comment: the result is true 12.34 But what if NSLog(@"%0.2f", 12.00); the result will 12.00 too 12 is the desire value

Comment: Sorry, missed that you wanted no zero fraction digits. @Dorada's answer should help you!